# MuleESB - Could not initialize class sun.awt.SunToolkit

Tags: java, web-services, mule

I am trying to reproduce the create a webservice via cxf following the example written by Brigilin Stanley here: http://confluex.com/blog/jax-ws-service-with-cxf-in-mule/

This works fine in Mule Studio, but I get a strange issue when I deploy to a linux red Hat server:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.awt.SunToolkit
        at sun.awt.AppContext$2.run(AppContext.java:271)
        at sun.awt.AppContext$2.run(AppContext.java:260)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.awt.AppContext.initMainAppContext(AppContext.java:260)
        at sun.awt.AppContext.access$200(AppContext.java:133)
        at sun.awt.AppContext$3.run(AppContext.java:316)
        at sun.awt.AppContext$3.run(AppContext.java:298)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.awt.AppContext.getAppContext(AppContext.java:297)
        at sun.awt.AppContext$6.getContext(AppContext.java:839)
        at sun.misc.SharedSecrets.getJavaAWTAccess(SharedSecrets.java:201)
        at java.util.TimeZone.getDefaultInAppContext(TimeZone.java:734)
        at java.util.TimeZone.getDefaultRef(TimeZone.java:630)
        at java.util.Calendar.getInstance(Calendar.java:968)
        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.AbsoluteTimeDateFormat.<init>(AbsoluteTimeDa
teFormat.java:62)
        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.ISO8601DateFormat.<init>(ISO8601DateFormat.j
ava:46)
        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.PatternParser.finalizeConverter(PatternParse
r.java:256)
        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.PatternParser.parse(PatternParser.java:186)
        at org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout.<init>(PatternLayout.java:438)
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Which Java (vendor and version) are you running there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This exception usually indicates that the server has no X server. To tell awt that you are in a "headless" server, use this Java system property: `-Djava.awt.headless=true`

Comment: Just wanted to say - eight months later, you're still a lifesaver. Four hours later I find you... <3 +1

Answer (score 1):

This problem *should* indicate that you are missing the headless argument, but for me the problem was that I was running with xvfb-run (and thus has a "display") but got the error nevertheless.

The solution was a missing dependency for libxtst6 and an install solved the problem:

```
apt-get install libxtst6
```

Answer (score -1):

This happens during Caused by:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/lwawt/liblwawt.dylib:
>   dlopen(/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/lwawt/liblwawt.dylib,
>   1): Library not loaded: @rpath/libosxapp.dylib   Referenced from:
>   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/lwawt/liblwawt.dylib
>   Reason: image not found

The problem is due to an update to the Mac OS that affects essentially DLL files that Java uses. This issue has been seen to occur to both the version of Java being updated on the system along with other applications as well (WebSense, others). 
The fix is to copy the libosxapp.dylib file that the application is trying to reference by copying the file to the same directory where the liblwawt.dylib resides (change the version of Java to match your own):

Here is the Fix:

```
sudo cp /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libosxapp.dylib lwawt/libosxapp.dylib
```